# ASP.Net Error 26 Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried everything: my connection string, turned off firewall, allowed remote connections, but I still keep getting this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to the SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6568558
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +717
>      System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +6595000
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +219
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6597311
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6597891
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +942
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1162
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +72
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +6601145
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +103
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2102
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1079
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6605639
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +207
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +438
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32() +582
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() +15
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +263
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +749
>      System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +314
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +329
>      System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +230
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +130
>      System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +267
>      System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +217
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +66
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +596
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +208
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +263
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +72
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +64
>      System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +218
>      System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +113
>      Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__13.MoveNext() +229
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
>      Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__d.MoveNext() +455
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +144
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +84
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +49
>      Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +235
>      DaveyMaherFitness.Logic.RoleActions.AddUserAndRole() +151
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12601933
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
>      System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
>      System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12618980
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12458597

Any advice would be appreciated, I feel like I'm just overlooking something!

Comment: Start with your connection string. Can you connect to SQL Server via Management Studio with those settings?

Comment: Yes, I can update it in VS and the changes appear in SQL Server Management Studio and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That simply states it could not establish a connection to the server and there could be dozen reason for that .

It could be the SQL-SERVER configured Windows Mode Authentication and you are trying sql-server authentication . 
Or your sql-server  is not configured for the remote connection 
or you are using wrong credential . 
or worst your connection string is not correct.

Any way , I highly recommend use Server panel in VS , and make test connection on that panel , It's much easier for you to figure it out what's wrong .

Comment: I've realized it was an error with my authentication, thank you for your help.